# How to join 3 columns and make it as a single column in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to join 3 columns and make it as a single column. While joining, if value is null, then replace it with default value (blank).

Input:
First Name, middle name, lastname
Priya, null, Raju
Ramesh, shakti, Prabha

Output:
Firstname, middlename, lastname, Fullname
Priya, null, Raju, Priya Raju
Ramesh, Shakti, Prabha, Ramesh Shakti Prabha

I used concat but if it has null how to replace with blank value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this expression `iifNull({ColumnName}, '')` to replace null.